# Help me identify this capacitor to fix my monitor

Tags: identification, surface-mount, repair

My monitor ( Samsung C32HG70 ) is having a common issue about 2 years in with horizontal/vertical line issues.

I've narrowed it down to this capacitor [image: 33 1E98 CAPACITOR] that I can tap on a bit and the back to normal the screen goes (need to get some canned air and see if freezing it fixes it).

My issue is deciphering the code 33 1E98. My best guess so far is a 33uF capacitor, although depending on what the elusive 1E98 code means that could be way off. The anode marking appears to be in the style of Sanyo tantalum smd capacitors. The catalog sheet I found for those though did not go down to 33uF and were rated at 10v (operating voltage across the capacitor is 18V).

I'll cross my fingers and try to fix the solder joints, but I'd like to be able to replace it if that doesn't work. If you're feeling froggy enough to help search for a moment, you have my heartfelt thanks.

Comment: reflow the solder

Comment: That's immediate plan since physical manipulation produced changes. Still, if it comes back in a few months, a replacement in the drawer will be worth more than the few dollars I'll spend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is your part:**
Very close to the picture below:
Note that the voltage rating of your part is different, the 1E code corresponds to a 25V rating, per the Panasonic data sheet below.
Yours is likely a P/N:
25TQC33MYF

.

.
[image]

Picture above is from:
https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/RE503APU06/33uF+16V+SMT+Solid+Polymer+Tantalum+Capacitor+Panasonic%C2%AE+16TQC33MYFS.html
.

.
Here is the direct Panasonic web site for a more detailed search:
https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AAA8000/AAA8000C62.pdf

.

**EDIT:**
In addition to simple component failures from over voltage/current/temperature there are additional physical issues that can effect SMT components. There is the possibility of the part or the electrical connection becoming physically broken or cracked due to stress on the PCB. Wider parts such as tantalum caps can be a bit more susceptible to stress cracks. If physical pressure on the part changes the performance you might suspect a cracked part or the connection. A small (or micro size) crack could be very difficult to see without magnification. A crack to the solder joint might be reparable by re-soldering, but cracks to the component body, lead to body, or pad to PCB may require part replacement or a PCB trace repair.
.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now the fun part of sorting through some sites to see if i can find a more robust replacement with equivalent critical specs along with a spare.

Answer (score -1):

Going off of @Nedd's answer, I've found the exact part. It seems to be the Panasonic 25TQC33MYF, which can be found [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/25TQC33MYF/4146598).

I would just replace it with the exact same part to ensure everything works normally, but if you really want to use a higher-spec one, your main options are to get a higher voltage rating (which I don't think would matter much) or a higher temperature rating. It would need to be in the same package (2917, though you may be able to fit a 2924) and have the same capacitance and roughly the same ESR. (If we knew more about the capacitor's function, it might be possible to use a lower ESR or higher capacitance as well, but with the information we have now, you shouldn't change those. They may be critical to a control loop.)

This part is rated for 33 μF, 60 mΩ ESR, 25 V, and 105 °C max temperature. It may be possible to replace with a KEMET [T599X336M035ATE065](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/T599X336M035ATE065/8627051), which is 33 μF, 65 mΩ, 35 V, and 150 °C, and costs a little bit more. Note however that this part's endurance rating is 1000 hours @ 150 °C (page 4 of the [datasheet](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_T2073_T59X.pdf), footnote *5), while the Panasonic has 2000 hours @ 105 °C; up to you which of those you consider better.